# Bing API Authorization not working - The authorization type you provided is not supported. Only Basic and OAuth are supported

Tags: php, azure, api, bing, azure-marketplace

I recently got an email from Microsoft saying that the Bing API was moving to the Windows Azure Marketplace. It seemed that the main difference between the new request was the authentication.

After reading many posts on forums, I found this:

```
$accountKey = '#########';
$api =  'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&$top=8&Query=';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($accountKey . ":" . $accountKey)
    )
));
$request = $api.'%27'.$q.'%27&$skip='.$start;
$result = file_get_contents($request, 0, $context);
```

However, I still get the error "The authorization type you provided is not supported. Only Basic and OAuth are supported".

Does anyone know how I can fix this. I have also tried cURL and that doesn't work.
Thanks to anyone who can find me a solution.

Comment: Did you urlencode your $q variable?

Comment: Microsoft was unable to provide insight?

Comment: @Sandrino Di Mattia I tried urlencode but that hasn't helped. I got the code above from the Microsoft Migration Guide: www.bing.com/webmaster/content/developers/ADM_MIGRATION_GUIDE.docx

I found the same code on another post on StackOverflow but both seem  to give the same error

Answer (score 3):

I think the URLs have changed. This code works. Note the URL in the first line:

```
$api = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?$format=json&$top=8&Query=';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($accountKey . ":" . $accountKey)
    )
));
$q = 'test';
$request = $api.'%27'.$q.'%27';

echo file_get_contents($request, 0, $context);
```

Comment: Sadly, that code doesn't work either - still giving the same error. I'm wondering whether it could be something to do with my server but I don't think so.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps there's a proxy that's somehow interfering? Aside from a missing `$accountKey = ...` line at the top, that code is verbatim what I just ran successfully.

Comment: Is it possible your account key is wrong? Double check it at https://datamarket.azure.com/account/keys?

Comment: You could be right. It seems when I run the page through my browser, I can type in the account key in the password slot and it can easily return the JSON result. It's only when I request the API through PHP using Authorization, does it fail.

Comment: I've double checked my account key and it works when I use the API through my browser.

Comment: Have you tried changing base64_encode($accountKey . ":" . $accountKey)
to: base64_encode("ignored:".$accountKey)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too yet nothing seems to work. Could someone find me a solution?

Comment: @user1603600 did you signup for the service? in my case i had to sign up to the particular service before i could use the php part

Comment: A suggestion to reduce traffic and raise speed: Add `Accept-Encoding: gzip`and remove the name in the auth. `base64_encode(':' . $accountKey)` is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here is working example of Search API just replace your access key with "XXXX". Even i wasted quite a few hours to get it work using cURL but it was failing cause of "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" on local :(

```
$url = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27xbox%27';
$process = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:XXXX");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($process);

# Deliver
return $response;

# Have a great day!
curl_close($process);
```

Comment: I've been able to fix this same issue thanks to your CURL code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, now fixed, the root_url has changed, it is now something like:
https://user:yourAccountKey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27leo%20fender%27&Market=%27en-US%27&$top=50&$format=JSON">

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem which occured when I deployed a website to a new server. I think my hosting company disabled some functionality with file_get_contents to external links.

```
    $url = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text=%27'.urlencode($text).'%27&To=%27' . $to . '%27&From=%27' . $from . '%27&$top=100&$format=json';

    $accountKey = 'APIKEY';
    $handle = curl_init ($url);
    if ($handle) {
        $curlOptArr = array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => $accountKey . ':' . $accountKey,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE

        );
        curl_setopt_array($handle, $curlOptArr);
        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        $data = json_decode($response,true);
        if (is_array($data)) {
            if (isset($data['d']['results'][0]['Text'])) {
                print $data['d']['results'][0]['Text'];
            } else {
                print false;
            }
        } else {
            print $text;
        }
        $errRet = curl_error($handle);
        curl_close($handle);
    }
```

This one works for me when using cURL.